# angularjs - parent scope not created but still visible on page

Tags: angularjs

I've a strange behaviour in my app.

Basically, I have a main page called details, and inside details a subview called `detailsAll` and `detailsEdit`.

the default one is `detailsAll`.

If I use the app navigating from `detailsAll` to `detailsEdit`, everything works fine, however, if I load the app directly from `detailsEdit`, the scope from `details` is undefined.

It make sense, since maybe it is still not created as I never reached that page yet, but why even if it is undefined (console.log prints undefined) i can still see the data printed on my page?

There's a better example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/qBtT5gkVSkYfjbngZVqw?p=preview

So, when you apen the app, the url is the following: `#/app/1(hard coded for test only)/edit/day/1` and so the first page is the detailsEdit subview.

As you can see, the scope called onlyOne (created from my parent) is visible on the page, but the same exact scope returns undefined in the console.

Same happens for `$scope.test = $scope.onlyOne`. Nothing displayed, but if you go back to the using the yellow button and then select something else, then it works.

It is easier to understand if you see it in action, so please refer to the plunker above.

Why is it doing that? I though it was something related with cache, but I tried to hard reset and nothing changed.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if parent scope has a property, then the child will inherit it's value, else it will create it's own property and assign an empty value to it. at a later point of time, if the parent defines the same property the child will just ignore parent's value
In your case, when you just open /app/1/edit/day/1, the child's `$scope.onlyOne`   is getting initialized with `{}` and parent's `$scope.onlyOne` is initialized at a later point of time as it is async call. this is the reason for the problem that you are facing.

one solution is to add a listener in the parent and propagate the value to the child once the async call is completed

https://plnkr.co/edit/9jS9qcwgecEJzqsD8L0z?p=preview

Comment: But why even if i actually ty to re-create the scope in the child using the same code that creates the same scope in the parent it still doesn't work?

Comment: it is a bad practice in term of memory to have it created again? what do you think it is the best and most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: like I said in the answer "add a listener in the parent and propagate the value to the child once the async call is completed"

Comment: added the listener part to the solution